# Local Variables Alignment in C code

Tags: c, struct, stack, padding

I'm trying to understand how packing of a struct variable affects the way local variables on the stack are assigned address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s
{
    short s1;
    short s2;
    short s3;
};

int main()
{
    struct s myStruct1;
    struct s myStruct2;

    myStruct1.s1 = 1;
    myStruct1.s2 = 2;
    myStruct1.s3 = 3;

    myStruct2.s1 = 4;
    myStruct2.s2 = 5;
    myStruct2.s3 = 6;

    int i = 0xFF;

    printf("Size of struct s: %d", sizeof(myStruct1));
    return 0;
}
```

In my program above, I have 2 struct variables and 1 integer. The GCC compiler has decided to assign addresses like this:

```
&i          0x00007FFFFFFFDF0C
&myStruct1  0x00007FFFFFFFDF10
&myStruct2  0x00007FFFFFFFDF20
```

There is no padding within the struct - the size of the struct is 6 bytes.

Question is why is myStruct2 on a 2-byte boundary when it could have been placed on the next 6 bytes after myStruct1?

Comment: @user3629249 But I'm not sure if what you say explains why &myStruct2  doesnt start immediately after &myStruct1 (at address: 0x00007FFFFFFFDF16)

Comment: the alignment of a struct depends on several factors, like the #pragma pack, the underlying architecture bus width, the largest alignment required for any member of the struct, certain parameters passed (or not passed) to the compiler, the addressable data size/alignment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `myStruct1` and `myStruct2` are two local variables, their address don't need to be next to each other. It's perfectly legal for GCC to put them like that.

Compare it with this:

```
struct s myStruct[2];
```

`myStruct[0]` and `myStrcut[1]` must be next to each other because they are in the same array.

Comment: What happens to the memory in between - isn't that going to be unused and therefore going to bloat the size of the stack frame if there were a large number of such variables? Maybe the stack is of little consideration in desktop world, but what about in embedded systems with very limited stack sizes?

Comment: I was suspicious  more by the observation that the int and struct variable and contiguous but the 2 struct variable arent

Comment: @NikhilJagdale This is unlikely to be the cause of stack overflow, coding error is. What GCC does is legal, unless you have some real evidence showing it's causing problems, that's it.

Comment: @YuHao @Electrix Padding is also applied to independent variables. Refer to [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/). In your case, the `struct s`'s alignment is `2` and it's size is `6`, you can investigate them through `alignof` and `sizeof`. So `myStruct1` and `myStruct2` are located at any addresses divisible by `2`. So, there is no need to padding inside of `struct st` at the end because its first member(therefore the next `struct st`) can be any addresses divisible by `2` automatically.

Comment: NOTE : As local variables, the way they are aligned is unpredictable because we can't know how are they placed in machine words. If `myStruct1` is placed in one word end and `myStruct2` is placed in the other word, there is no need to padding any bytes! Also we should care about cache line's width. In your case there are `10`(`0x16` ~ `0x1f`) bytes padding between two `struct s`s.